# Extracting a string between last two slashes in Bash

Tags: bash

I know this can be easily done using regex like I answered on https://stackoverflow.com/a/33379831/3962126, however I need to do this in bash.

So the closest question on Stackoverflow I found is this one [bash: extracting last two dirs for a pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8223170/3962126), however the difference is that if

```
DIRNAME = /a/b/c/d/e
```

then I need to extract

```
d
```

Comment: Does `$(basename $(dirname "$DIRNAME"))` meet your requirements?  Failing that, does `x=${DIRNAME%/*}; echo ${x##*/}` do the job you require?  Beware degenerate cases.

Comment: I saw your comment after I posted my answer below. Yes, it does. I really don't understand how/why this command extracts the string between the last two slashes, but I don't care as far as it works for me.

Comment: The `dirname` command drops the last component of the file name, removing the `/e`; the `basename` command drops all except the last component of the file name, removing the `/a/b/c`, leaving just `d`.

Comment: @Jonathan, notice the solution `x=${DIRNAME%/*}; echo ${x##*/}` also matches `d` here: `DIRNAME=a/b`, and I think that's not what the OP wants.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, that's a bit buggy as given -- you need quotes around the dirname expansion too.

Comment: @Sasha, can you speak to what behavior you want if `DIRNAME=d/e` or `DIRNAME=e`?

Comment: @j.a.: I said 'Beware degenerate cases'; you're telling me that I need to be careful of degenerate cases.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: It's commentary to get towards an answer; it is not a polished solution.   It works on the sample data; it is not fully generalized.  And if you keep within the portable file name character set (and even with a moderate number of extensions over the base portable file name character set), the quotes aren't necessary.  The problem is that people don't keep within the portable file name character set.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, ...and restricting names to that set is an utterly unrealistic request to make of people. Folks whose native language uses a different alphabet should be able to name files in that language. Support for whitespace within filenames, likewise, is a reasonable end-user expectation of anyone coming from major desktop operating systems.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, ...moreover, even if names *were* restricted to that set, we can't say whether names will survive unquoted expansion unmodified without knowing the value of IFS. And regardless -- failing to quote is asking the shell to do *more* processing, in a case where that processing isn't desired or necessary. In what world is running data through unneeded, irrelevant processing a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG, maybe this was obvious, but not to me initially. I got the right result with:

```
dir=$(basename -- "$(dirname -- "$str")")
echo "$dir"
```

Comment: The correct way to write that would have been `dir=$(basename "$(dirname "$str")")`.

Comment: ...otherwise, you'll get bugs when your strings contain whitespace, glob expressions that match files, etc.

Comment: ...also, this is slow enough that you wouldn't want to put it in an inner loop that's run hundreds or thousands of times; command substitutions (that is, the `$(...)` syntax) have a substantial performance penalty.

Answer (score 12):

This may be relatively long, but it's also much faster to execute than most preceding answers (other than the zsh-only one and that by j.a.), since it uses only string manipulations built into bash and uses no subshell expansions:

```
string='/a/b/c/d/e'  # initial data
dir=${string%/*}     # trim everything past the last /
dir=${dir##*/}       # ...then remove everything before the last / remaining
printf '%s\n' "$dir" # demonstrate output
```

`printf` is used in the above because `echo` doesn't work reliably for all values (think about what it would do on a GNU system with `/a/b/c/-n/e`).

Comment: This might be the best answer as it's also stricly POSIX-compliant.

Comment: The only problem with this @gniourf is that it matches also any string before the last slash (e.g. `string="d/e"` matches `d`) and the OP asked for the string between the last **two** slashes.

Comment: It even prints any string if there is no slashes (e.g.: `string=hello` -> prints `hello`).

Comment: @j.a., I don't read either case as a bug -- both fall outside the assumptions implicit in the specification. If one wanted to put in a `if [[ $string = */*/* ]]; then` ... `fi` wrapping this code to avoid them both, trivially done.

Comment: It should be noted that this solution performs significantly better than that of @j.a. at scale. Even with the above check in place, I see ~1.07 seconds for 1,000,000 iterations on the path `/home/a/b/c/d/e/f/g.txt`, vs. ~7.57 seconds for the regex replacement solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here a pure `bash` solution:

```
[[ $DIRNAME =~ /([^/]+)/[^/]*$ ]] && printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Compared to some of the other answers:

- It matches the string between the last **two** slashes. So, for example, it doesn't match `d` if `DIRNAME=d/e`.
- It's shorter and fast (just uses built-ins and doesn't create subprocesses).
- Support any character between last two slashes (see [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33380299/4095830) for more on this).

---

Also notice that is not the way to assign a variable in `bash`:

```
DIRNAME = /a/b/c/d/e
       ^ ^
```

Those spaces are wrong, so remove them:

```
DIRNAME=/a/b/c/d/e
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
echo "/a/b/c/d/e" | awk -F / '{ print $(NF-1) }' # d
```

Edit: This does not work when the path contains newlines, and still gives output when there are less than two slashes, see comments below.

Comment: This also matches `d` here: `DIRNAME=a/b` and the OP asked for the string between the last **two** slashes.

Comment: This even prints any string if there is no slashes (e.g.: `echo hello | awk -F / '{ print $(NF-1) }'` -> prints `hello`).

Comment: ...and gives incorrect results when the filename contains literal newlines.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

if you want to get the fourth element

```
DIRNAME="/a/b/c/d/e"
echo "$DIRNAME" | sed -r 's_^(/[^/]*){3}/([^/]*)/.*$_\2_g'
```

if you want to get the before last element

```
DIRNAME="/a/b/c/d/e"
echo "$DIRNAME" | sed -r 's_^.*/([^/]*)/[^/]*$_\1_g'
```

Comment: Wildly inefficient compared to using built-in string manipulation. (Though that's true of the awk answer and the basename/dirname one too).

Comment: Also, buggy due to lack of quotes -- look at what happens if your `DIRNAME` contains a glob expression that actually matches anything, or runs of whitespace.

Comment: yes, is better string manipulation, only, `sed` is another solution ..... in which test case failure, a example?

Comment: Consider for instance `DIRNAME='/a/b/c/ * d * /e'`, where the whitespace and literal asterisk are part of the directory name.

Comment: Will also behave weirdly if there are newlines in `DIRNAME`.

Answer (score 0):

Using zsh parameter substitution is pretty cool too

```
echo ${${DIRNAME%/*}##*/}
```

I think it's faster than the double $() as well, because it won't need any subprocesses.

Basically it slices off the right side first, and then all the remaining left side second.

Comment: Which version of Bash supports that nested substitution?  `zsh` does, but not Bash AFAIK — but I'm here to learn too.